# How do I get natural json notation from app engine?

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine, rest, google-cloud-endpoints

I have built a REST application with Jersey and didn't succeed in getting natural notation out of JAXB. I simply adapted my GWT application to cast the wrongly transmitted types to what I wanted. I know, not the best solution, but there were no time for something else.

Now that I try to set up cloud endpoints on app engine and get the exact same format which is not what google show in their examples, I suspect that there is something I have missed regarding GAE.

This is what I want from GAE:

```
{
"anumberprop":123,
"atextprop":"blah",
"anarray":[{"another_no":432}]
}
```

This is what I actually get:

```
{
"anumberprop":"123",
"atextprop":"blah",
"anarray":{"another_no":"432"}
}
```

This causes problems since the client will be a GWT app or a Google Apps Script which parses the JSON internally and this will give a lot of exceptions when the types don't match.

What am I doing wrong?

Best regards,
Peter

Answer (score 1):

The 432 vs "432" is likely because Cloud Endpoints quotes 64-bit integers so JavaScript clients can use a standard JSON parser without losing precision on those numbers. I'm unable to reproduce the missing array brackets. Can you post your response object?

Comment: Thanks saiyr, you're right. The number I was using was a Long variable. Using an int gives what I expected. Also, the brackets are where I expected them to be with the cloud endpoints. However, the question above still holds for REST-services using Jersey. It would be interesting to know how to control the JSON notation in such circumstances.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not entirely clear what you're asking now (I'm not familiar with Jersey). My impression was that you were getting incorrect output from Endpoints because the value of "anarray" was, in fact, not an array. Is that not the case?

Comment: When using Jersey, it defaults to "mapped" JSON notation where all types are sent as strings, and if an array only contains a single object it's sent without the square brackets. Since the cloud endpoints seems to behave correctly, I was wondering then if someone knows how to configure app engine to deliver natural JSON notation when using Jersey.